# First Boeing 757-200 N757A 'Catfish' was modified with a Canard foreplane. How did it behave?

Tags: aircraft-performance, stability, flight-dynamics, canard, boeing-757

The aircraft had these changes made around 2006 to act as an F-22 Avionics test bed. One would expect that the fore plane changed many performances of machine, including take off and landing attitude and behavior. I am interested in knowing more about results of adding the canard fore plane to a series airliner.

A similar arrangement was proposed, it was promissory even at hyper sonic speeds, in a Naval Research Centre in California, for the Space Shuttle.

[image][Source: Airliners.net](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Boeing/Boeing-757-200-Catfish/1115914)

Comment: My god that looks hideous!

Comment: It is... _unique_... @Jpe61

Comment: Hope it stays unique.

Comment: As you said, it was added for electronics development, and for the F22, information is probably difficult to find for such a program... Also, the canard is generally useful at high attack angles, which was probably never tested for this 757

Comment: That must be the airplane that The Flying Nun uses.

Comment: I was aware about comment by BambOo, but no one answered the issue yet, question is about the flight behavior and performance changes due to the Canard on N757A, if any. Or is this an industrial or state secret? This was cited: 'Flowfield Computations over the Space Shuttle Orbiter with a Proposed Canard at a Mach Number of 5.8 and 50 Degrees Angle of Attack', by William H Reuter, June 1993, Naval Postgraduate School, Monterey, California (Nice music festival, that) Blessings +